# How to set a custom SSH connection response string?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

Is it possible to modify the string that the OpenSSH server displays when a raw connection is established?

<sub>It is not about the text banner displayed *after* the connection is established and which can be configured by the `Banner` parameter in `sshd_config`, but about the raw output the SSH server sends on a connection attempt before the handshake.</sub>

For example, given a raw telnet connection

```
$ telnet localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2
```

is there a way to reduce identifying information to the bare minimum?

My understanding is that `SSH-2.0-` must be present because it is required by the SSH protocol, but the string that follows - `OpenSSH_7.2p2` - is probably not required by the protocol but I can't see a way to change or remove it without recompiling.

The intent is to avoid providing more info than strictly necessary for the protocol to work.

Comment: No. [Prevent SSH from advertising its version number](https://serverfault.com/questions/216801/prevent-ssh-from-advertising-its-version-number).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The version string is defined in version.h of [OpenSSH source](https://www.openssh.com/openbsd.html) as

`#define SSH_VERSION    "OpenSSH_7.4"`.

You could change it, but it requires recompiling.

It is then <s>send</s> put together via:

`snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "SSH-2.0-%.100s\r\n", SSH_VERSION)`

(ssh_api.c line 381, in function `_ssh_send_banner`)

See also: [Prevent SSH from advertising its version number](https://serverfault.com/questions/216801/prevent-ssh-from-advertising-its-version-number).

Answer (score 2):

Recent OpenSSH versions allow adding custom text via `VersionAddendum`, but do not allow removing the product name/version. You'll have to patch the source code for that.